# how to fix "expo-cli" issus on windows 10?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

i want to install expo-cli on my windows 10 to start a new react native project : i have node js installed with version v10.15.0 but when i enter : "npm install -g expo-cli" but some issus and this are the kind of errors that appears after the installation

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.22.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.22.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sami_\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-21T18_38_29_235Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting almost 1 day, I resolved this issue, this error is due to sharp

If you are having issues during installation consider removing the directory `C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_libvips`

```
npm install -g sharp # (The installation require python 2.7 on windows and path env configuration)

npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: I'm getting errors installing sharp. What do you mean by path env configuration?

Comment: Never mind. I've got it working with a local, not global install (and npx). I wonder if npx had something to do with the errors.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I used yarn instead of npm.

```sh
yarn global add sharp
```

Then

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

After that, if you run

```
 expo
```

And got

> expo is not a command

Which means you need to

add yarn global packages to the envirmonment variable. And your yarn global packages might in *C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin*.

Also, I installed python 2.7 in the beginning. Not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the expo-cli folder in AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules then reinstalling expo worked for me.